# Carrossel ASP Clássico (Concatenação)

Tags: asp, carousel

boa tarde.
Usei um carrossel para fazer uma galeria de imagens simples.
Nomeei numericamente os nomes das fotos (1.JPG, 2.JPG, 3.JPG, ... , n.JPG)
Fazendo "manualmente" (ou seja, quando eu digito o código inteiro, inserindo cada imagem da pasta de fotos), obviamente dá tudo certo.

Mas eu gostaria de fazer isso com um loop. Mas tem algo errado, acredito que talvez seja na concatenação.

Segue o código, no exemplo abaixo, eu tenho 29 imagens.

```
  <div id="galeria" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">   
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
          <img src="img/1.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <% For i=2 to 29 %>
        <div class="carousel-item">
          <img src="img/"<% & i & %>".jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
        </div>
        <% Next %>
    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#galeria" role="button" data-slide="prev">
       <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       <span class="sr-only">Anterior</span>   
    </a>   
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#galeria" role="button" data-slide="next">
       <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
       <span class="sr-only">Próxima</span>   
    </a> 
</div>
```

Alguma ideia?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Está errado mesmo isso: `<% & i & %>`. O certo seria: `<%=i%>`, que irá puxar o valor de `i` do `for` e inserir no HTML. E não se trata propriamente de uma concatenação, você só quer pegar o valor da variável para inserir no código HTML.

E não precisa das aspas extras no código ASP. Seria:

```
<img src="img/<%=i%>.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
```

As aspas são apenas para delimitar o valor do atributo `src`. O código ASP, delimitado por `<% %>`, é um código independente processado no servidor, ou seja, o `<%=i%>` será de 2 a 29, resultando no HTML:

```
<img src="img/2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
<img src="img/3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
<img src="img/4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
...até o 29
```

A forma `<%=i%>` é uma forma curta de `<% Response.Write(i) %>` ou `<% Response.Write i %>`.

Comment: valeu!!! era isso mesmo!  eu sabia que o problema estava no <%& i & %>, eu só não sabia como corrigir!